# Cucumber + Capybara Checking for text appearing multiple times

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to check if a given string appears multiple times in some scenarios

I found this elsewhere:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" twice$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new(text + "(.+)" + text)
  response.body.should contain(regexp)
end
```

Which was written for webrat. I'm trying to express it with Capybara:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" twice$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new(text + "(.+)" + text)
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_xpath('//*', :text => regexp)
  else
    assert page.has_xpath?('//*', :text => regexp)
  end
end
```

Which gives me expected #has_xpath("//*") to return true, got false

I also tried a multiline variant of the above regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I ended up using after messing with the regexp. I gather that "([^/]*)" will takes something as a regular expression versus "([^"]*)" taking something as plaintext:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\/]*)" "(.+)" times$/ do |regexp, times|
  str = regexp
  for i in times
    str = str + "(.+)" + regexp
  end
  regexp = Regexp.new(str)
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_xpath('//*', :text => regexp)
  else
    assert page.has_xpath?('//*', :text => regexp)
  end
end
```